# TypeError: TimestampType can not accept object <class 'str'> and <class 'int'>

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pandas dataframe that I am writing to a table in HDFS.  I can write the data to a table when the `Srum_Entry_Creation` is `StringType()`, but I need it to be `TimestampType()`.  This is where I am running into `TypeError: TimestampType can not accept object '2019-05-20 12:03:00' in type <class 'str'>` or `TypeError: TimestampType can not accept object 1558353780000000000 in type <class 'int'>`. I have tried converting the column to different date formats in python, before defining the schema but can seem to get the import to work.

```
df
    Srum_Entry_ID   Connected_Time  Machine     Srum_Entry_Creation
0   5769.0          0.018218        Computer1   2019-05-20 12:03:00
1   5770.0          0.000359        Computer1   2019-05-20 12:03:00
2   5771.0          0.042674        Computer2   2019-05-20 13:03:00
3   5772.0          0.043229        Computer2   2019-05-20 14:04:00
4   5773.0          0.032222        Computer3   2019-05-20 14:04:00

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('application').getOrCreate()
schema = StructType([StructField('Srum_Entry_ID', FloatType(), False),
                     StructField('Connected_Time', FloatType(), True),
                     StructField('Machine', StringType(), True),
                     StructField('Srum_Entry_Creation', TimestampType(), True)])
dataframe = spark.createDataFrame(df, schema)
dataframe.write. \
  mode("append"). \
  option("path", "/user/hive/warehouse/analytics.db/srum_network_connections"). \
  saveAsTable("analytics.srum_network_connections")
```

I have tried:

```
df['Srum_Entry_Creation'] = df['Srum_Entry_Creation'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

error:
`TypeError: TimestampType can not accept object 1558353780000000000 in type <class 'int'>`

**and**

```
df['Srum_Entry_Creation'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Srum_Entry_Creation'])
```

error: 
`TypeError: TimestampType can not accept object 1558353780000000000 in type <class 'int'>`

**and** if I just leave it as a string in the pandas dataframe I get:

error: `TypeError: TimestampType can not accept object '2019-05-20 12:03:00' in type <class 'str'>`

Comment: have you tried to replace it with a datetime format ?

Comment: I have tried df['Srum_Entry_Creation'] = df['Srum_Entry_Creation'].astype('datetime64[ns]') and df['Srum_Entry_Creation'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Srum_Entry_Creation'])

Comment: and what are the errors ? the same ?

Comment: I added them to the question @Steven

Comment: Is it an option, exporting the timestamp as string from spark and convert it later? I know it kind of hurts, because it means extra conversions, but if it works?! or is it maybe possible to use `numpy.datetime64` in place of `TimestampType()`, because it seems the class that is used as `TimestampType` is not convertable to `numpy.timestamp64` which pandas uses imho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short I converted the datetime to epoch time

```
df['epoch'] = (df['New_Srum_Entry_Creation'] - dt.datetime(1970,1,1)).dt.total_seconds()
df['epoch'] = df['epoch'].astype('Int64')
```

Then used IntegerType() for the schema

```
StructField('epoch', IntegerType(),True)
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the original question.